# Display different image depending on variable/key in URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using a query string in my URL to indicate a product choice. I used this function to have the product choice appear in a hidden text box that would be submitted to our website:

```
function getQueryVariable(key) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0])== key) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
}

var product = getQueryVariable('product');
document.getElementById("00NK0000000Yqv2").value = product;
```

I also need to show a header image depending on what product is indicated in the URL query string. I have four products (Manufacturing, Construction, Professional, and General).

How can I make it so that if the url is something like: [www.foo.com?product=Construction](http://www.foo.com?product=Construction) that it shows the construction header or if it is [www.foo.com?product=Manufacturing](http://www.foo.com?product=Manufacturing), it shows manufacturing instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the source of the image like so :

```
document.getElementById("headerImg").src = 'header' + product + '.jpg';
```

Where the image would have the same ID like so:

```
<img id="headerImg" src="images/headerImg.jpg">
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work with multiple images. I have to give each of my images a unique ID, so I don't see how the script you wrote would work.

Comment: In my example there is just one img tag which gets changed(via src attribute) to whatever image results from the URL variable "product". When you change the "src" attribute the browser then starts to dynamically load the new image.

Comment: Haven't been able to get it to work this way yet. Will keep trying though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css class of an element to your product name and swap out the background image in the CSS. For example, if your header element has an id = header, it would look like this using jquery.

$('#header').addClass(product); //Where product is your variable

Then in your CSS, you can style it as so:

#header {background-image: url(pathToDefaultImage)}

#header.Manufacturing {background-image: url(pathToManufacturingImage)}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do it in the same way you're setting the `value` - set the `src` attribute of an image based on your query variable.

Something like:

```
var image;
if (product === 'Construction') image = 'your_construction_image.png';
// more cases

document.getElementById('yourimageID').src = image;
```

A better approach to this, however, would be using your server-side language to render the HTML you want instead of setting it after with JavaScript.